# How can I keep windows from being shrunk past their fill-columns?

Tags: window, window-splitting, fill-column

Typically I have two windows, left and right, with the left window (call it the "editing window") showing a buffer in a prog-mode or text-mode and the right window (call it the "auxiliary window") showing something else: documentation, Magit, `make` output, or just the start-up screen.

My font size and frame width are such that, if these windows' widths are *balanced*, the editing window is (by a small amount) not wide enough to show all its content out to its fill-column, while the auxiliary window has more width than it typically needs.  I would like Emacs to keep the windows sized so that the editing window (or each window, for simplicity) has enough width to show its fill-column.

I have the following Elisp running in the `prog-mode-hook` and the `text-mode-hook`:

```el
   (setq-local fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally t)
   (let (w (get-buffer-window))
     (fit-window-to-buffer w nil nil nil (+ fill-column 8))
     (window-preserve-size w t t)))
```

(The added 8 columns are to account for the fringes, line numbers, etc.)

If I start Emacs as `emacs <FILE>`, such that it opens with a left window showing FILE and a right window showing the start-up screen, the above code does make the left window larger, such that its fill-column is visible. However, if I then open Magit or a help window, or run `make` with Projectile, such that Magit or help or `make` takes over the right window, or even if I open another file with `C-x C-f` in the left window, the windows' widths become *balanced*, such that the left window may no longer be wide enough to show all of FILE (depending on its fill-column) and Magit or whatever has more width than it needs.

**How can I make Emacs respect windows' buffers' fill-columns when resizing windows?**

I have seen the [window hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Hooks.html), but those seemed promising only until I saw "Window change functions should not [...] change the [...] size [...] of any window".

I considered `window-min-height` and `window-min-width`, but they, as I understand it, apply only to all windows, which is unsatisfactory, as the width I want varies by buffer. I tried `window-size-fixed`, but, by fixing the height of the editing window, it prevented completions from appearing at the bottom of the frame.

Comment: You might try writing a custom function to assign to the `split-window` parameter for windows you wish to have special behaviour?  You could then use a window change hook to add or remove that parameter, in accordance with the buffer it was currently displaying.  (Suggestion is entirely untested by me.)

Comment: I tried putting a function in that parameter to write a message into `*Messages*`, which shows that it doesn't get called when I (for example) open Magit, which is as I expected: I didn't think any window was getting split; rather, the existing left window gets repurposed for Magit/help/`make`.

Comment: The variables `window-min-height` and `window-min-width` can be helpful to control the minimum size vertically and horizontally.  See also the variable `window-size-fixed`.  The doc-strings describe how those variables may be used.

Comment: `window-size-fixed` definitely looks useful here.  Perhaps `display-buffer-alist` could be used to set the window width when displaying the buffer (see  `C-h i g (elisp)Buffer Display Action Alists`) and `window-size-fixed` could prevent other things from changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2022-05-17, I found that my problem is solved by setting the window width from `window-configuration-change-hook`, by running this in `prog-mode-hook` and `text-mode-hook`:

```el
   (setq-local fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally t)
   (add-hook
    'window-configuration-change-hook
    'user570286/set-window-width-per-content
    nil t)
   (user570286/set-window-width-per-content)
```

with this definition of `user570286/set-window-width-per-content`:

```el
(defun user570286/set-window-width-per-content ()
  "[...]"
  (let (w (get-buffer-window))
    (fit-window-to-buffer w nil nil nil (+ fill-column 9))))
```

(with a different name than "user570286" in the original code).

This solution does prevent me from being able to change window widths manually, but I'm okay with that.